# Is boost::thread thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety, boost-thread

is boost::thread object thread-safe? Should I lock calling of member methods of boost::thread (e.g. join) to be thread-safe?

EDIT 1: Please don't bother with my purpose. Can you simply answer the question?

EDIT 2 (for those who are not satisfied with EDIT 1):
My purpose is:
Consider one procedure as program for the thread, one procedure which stops that thread. Thread procedure is a while loop checking condition whether to continue. Stop procedure sets the condition to FALSE and wait to the end of the thread (join) and then perform some other actions. The point is that the stop procedure can call more than one thread.

**But my question is general, consider some next billion threads calling simultaneously member methods of one thread object such as get_id(), native_handle() etc.**

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your question. Under which circumstances would you need to control a thread from multiple other threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining a thread should only be done from a single other thread (preferably the thread that started it). There is no point for thread-safety in this case

Ok, I've actually looked through the source code of boost::thread:

```
void thread::join()
{
    detail::thread_data_ptr const local_thread_info=(get_thread_info)();
    if(local_thread_info)
    {
        bool do_join=false;

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(local_thread_info->data_mutex);
            while(!local_thread_info->done)
            {
                local_thread_info->done_condition.wait(lock);
            }
            do_join=!local_thread_info->join_started;

            if(do_join)
            {
                local_thread_info->join_started=true;
            }
            else
            {
                while(!local_thread_info->joined)
                {
                    local_thread_info->done_condition.wait(lock);
                }
            }
        }
        if(do_join)
        {
            void* result=0;
            BOOST_VERIFY(!pthread_join(local_thread_info->thread_handle,&result));
            lock_guard<mutex> lock(local_thread_info->data_mutex);
            local_thread_info->joined=true;
            local_thread_info->done_condition.notify_all();
        }

        if(thread_info==local_thread_info)
        {
            thread_info.reset();
        }
    }
}
```

And it appears that yes, it is thread-safe.

Comment: Ok, this is what I wanted to know. Thanks :-)

Comment: boost::thread is not thread safe for a basic reason: the same instance of a smart_ptr can not be safely copied and destroyed by two different threads.

Comment: @Gaetano Mendola: I was talking about `join` here, not all of `boost::thread`. Anyway, `join` should not be called from a different thread than the one that spawned the child thread imo.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::thread` **is not** thread safe.